# Question regarding Lorentz Transformation formula

Tags: special-relativity

So the Lorentz Transformation formation equation are
$$x′=\gamma(x−vt),$$

1. Does $x′$ and t represent time and position at one event(one instance) or do they represent two events- meaning is $x'$ actually $x_2-x_1$
2. I am rather confused on when to use the Lorentz equation for solving problems? Can't I just use the time dilation and length contraction formulas depending on the problem's constraints?

Answer (score 2):

The equation you've given is not the full Lorentz transformation. There is also a transformation giving t'.

> Does x' and t represent time and position at one event(one instance) or do they represent two events- meaning is x′ actually x2−x1

It works for either purpose.

> Can't I just use the time dilation and length contraction formulas depending on the problem's constraints?

No. If length contraction and time dilation were all there was, then it would be equivalent to simply changing the units used for time and distance. The Lorentz transformation also says that different observers don't agree on whether events happened in the same place (also true for Galilean relativity) and that they don't agree on whether events happened at the same time.